# Meteor collection not updating subscription on client

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm quite new on Meteor and Mongo and even if I don't want it, I need some relations.

I have a Collection called Feeds and another called UserFeeds where I have a feedid and a userid, and I publish the user feeds on the server like this:

```
Meteor.publish('feeds', function(){
    return Feeds.find({_id:{$in:_.pluck(UserFeeds.find({user:this.userId}).fetch(),'feedid')}});
});
```

I find the user on UserFeeds, fetch it (returns an array) and pluck it to have only the feedid field, and then find those feeds on the Feeds collection.

And subscribe on the client like this:

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
   Meteor.subscribe("feeds");
});
```

The problem is that when I add a new feed and a new userfeed the client doesn't receive the change, but when I refresh the page the new feed does appear.

Any idea of what I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: What was the solution to this problem facing situation like this ---- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652958/how-to-update-data-getting-from-meteor-subscription-when-value-updated-somewhere

Answer (score 16):

I've run into this, too.  It turns out publish functions on the server don't re-run reactively: if they return a Collection cursor, as you're doing (and as most publish functions do), then the publish function will run once and Meteor will store the cursor and send down updates only when the contents of the cursor change.  The important thing here is that Meteor will *not* re-run the publish function, nor, therefore, the `Collection.find(query)`, when `query` changes.  If you want the publish function to re-run, then the way I've done it so far is to set up the publish function to receive an argument.  That way the client, whose collections *do* update reactively, can re-subscribe reactively.  The code would look something like:

```
// client
Meteor.subscribe('user_feeds');

Deps.autorun(function(){ 
  var allFeeds = UserFeeds.find({user: Meteor.userId()}).fetch();
  var feedIds = _.pluck(allFeeds,'feedid');
  Meteor.subscribe('feeds',feedids);
});

// server
Meteor.publish('feeds',function(feedids) {
  return Feeds.find({_id: {$in: feedids}});
});
```

I believe the Meteorite package [publish-with-relations](https://github.com/erundook/meteor-publish-with-relations) is designed to solve this problem, although I haven't used it.

EDIT: I believe the publish function *will* re-run when the userId changes, which means that you can have a server-side check to make sure the user is logged in before publishing sensitive data.

Comment: I am having the same problem where I am using Alanning Roles package for Groups/Roles, and trying to filter the publish based on the user's roles (which change).  I am subscribing in the Iron Router `waitOn`, so I guess I need to move that out somewhere.  Would you recommend moving the subscribe in the `create` or maybe the `rendered`?

Comment: What if there are three collections: users, items and permissions. Items are published to users accordingly to permissions. Permissions can change and we want that change to be reflected immediately. We can't just accept user ID or permission ID or effective permissions from client side by "Meteor.publish" function because of security reason, right?

Answer (score 11):

I think your problem is that .fetch() which you use here…

```
UserFeeds.find({user:this.userId}).fetch()
```

…removes the reactivity.

.fetch() returns an array instead of a cursor, and that array won't be reactive.

http://docs.meteor.com/#fetch

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
Meteor.autosubscribe(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe("feeds");
});
```

and in the Template JS ...

```
Template.templateName.feeds = function() 
  return Feeds.find() # or any specific call
};
```

in the HTML ...

```
{{#each feeds}}
   do some stuff
{{else}}
   no feed
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is not on the client, but in the server, the client renders the feeds just fine, the problem is when a new feed is created and related to the user it doesn't push the change to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reactive-publish](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish) package (I am one of authors). It allows you to create publish endpoints which depend on the result of another query. In your case, query on `UserFeeds`.

```
Meteor.publish('feeds', function () {
    this.autorun(function (computation) {
        var feeds = _.pluck(UserFeeds.find({user: this.userId}, {fields: {feedid: 1}}).fetch(), 'feedid');
        return Feeds.find({_id: {$in: feeds}});
    });
});
```

The important part is that you limit the `UserFeeds` fields only to `feedid` to make sure `autorun` does not rerun when some other field changes in `UserFeeds`, a field you do not care about.